# Is there some sort of irrep orthogonality for finite groups?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, characters

Disclaimer: As pointed out by several people the original orthogonality condition I was asking about seems to be incorrect so I'm just going to change the question to the orthogonality condition addressed in the answer below.

---

Let $ \pi_1, \pi_2 $ be distinct irreps of a finite group $ G $. Let $ \chi_1, \chi_2 $ be the corresponding characters. Then we know that
$$
\sum_{g \in G} \chi_1(g) \chi_2(g)^*=0
$$
Dropping the trace (and assuming that $ \pi_1, \pi_2 $ have the same degree in particular $ \pi_1: G \to GL_d(\mathbb{C}) $ , $ \pi_2: G \to GL_d(\mathbb{C}) $ ) consider the sum
$$
\sum_{g \in G}  \pi_1(g)   \pi_2(g)^*
$$
Is there some sort of "orthogonality" here as well? In other words, for two distinct irreps $ \pi_1,\pi_2 $ of the same degree do we have that
$$
\sum_{g \in G}  \pi_1(g)   \pi_2(g)^*
$$
is the zero matrix?

Of course this is true for degree $ 1 $ by character orthogonality. Is it true for higher degree irreps?

Comment: What does the multiplication $\pi_1(g)\pi_2(g^{-1})$ mean? A priori, $\pi_1$ is a representation of $V_1$ and $\pi_2$ is a representation of $V_2$, so they are linear operators on different spaces.

Comment: @KentaS ok I changed them to be matrix reps now

Comment: Intuitively, such a statement should not exist. Indeed, if you replace $\pi_2$ with $A\pi_2A^{-1}$ for some invertible matrix $A$, the representation should not change. However, the matrix is changed significantly.

Comment: @KentaS That turns out not to matter. This isn't actually that surprising: change of basis doesn't break the vanishing condition since conjugating the zero matrix has no effect (nor does it affect the identity matrix if $\pi_1\cong\pi_2$). See the discussion about coordinate-dependence in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's generalize. Suppose $(V_1,\pi_1)$ and $(V_2,\pi_2)$ are two irreps of $G$. Define

$$ T(M)=\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G} \pi_1(g)M\pi_2(g^{-1}). \tag{$\color{green}{\triangle1}$}$$

Observe $T$ is a linear operator on the vector space $\hom(V_2,V_1)$. Your original question was when $\dim V_1=\dim V_2$ and $M=I$, but this restriction is not necessary.

Observe that for any $M\in\hom(V_2,V_1)$, the operator $T(M)$ is equivariant, i.e. for any $a\in G$,

$$ \pi_1(a)T(M)=T(M)\pi_2(a), $$

by reindexing the summation and using socks-and-shoes. By Schur's lemma, if $\pi_1\not\cong\pi_2$ there are no intertwiners, so $T(M)=0$ for all $M$.

If $\pi_1=\pi_2$ then $T(M)=\lambda(M)I$ for some linear scalar function $\lambda(M)$ of $M$. Taking the trace in the definition $({\color{green}\triangle})$ yields $\mathrm{tr}\,M=d_1\lambda(M)$, where $d_1$ is the dimension, so

$$ T(M)=\delta_{\pi_1\pi_2}\frac{\mathrm{tr}\,M}{d_1}I. \tag{$\color{green}{\triangle2}$}$$

Note this implies the worry about coordinate-dependence expressed in the comments is not a problem. Indeed, if we define the conjugate $\pi_1'(g)=A\pi_1(g)A^{-1}$ for some $A\in\mathrm{GL}(V_1)$, and define $T'$ accordingly, we get $T'(M)=AT(A^{-1}M)$, so the same conclusions holds for $T'$ as $T$, and similarly if we use a conjugate of $\pi_2$ as well (assuming $\pi_1\not\cong\pi_2$).

---

Recall we have an isomorphism of reps $\hom(V_2,V_1)\cong V_1\otimes V^\ast_2$. Say we view $V_1,V_2$ as spaces of column vectors. We can view $V_2^\ast$ either as the same vector space and apply $\pi_2^\ast(g)=\pi_2(g^{-1})^T$ from the left, or we can view it as a space of row vectors on which we apply $\pi_2(g^{-1})$ from the right. This allows us to reinterpret $T$ from the linear operator $(\color{green}{\triangle1})$ on $\hom(V_2,V_1)$ to a linear operator $({\color{Magenta}\diamondsuit})$ on $V_1\otimes V_2^\ast$ ("transport of structure") given by

$$ T=\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G} \pi_1(g)\otimes \pi_2(g^{-1})^T, \tag{$\color{Magenta}\diamondsuit$}$$

where we interpret $V_2^\ast$ as comprised of column vectors. If we view $V_2^\ast$ instead as comprised of row vectors, then the isomorphism $V_1\otimes V_2^\ast\cong\hom(V_2,V_1)$ is given by $v_1\otimes v_2^T\mapsto v_1v_2^T$ and we don't transpose $\pi_2(g^{-1})$ anymore; this is why $\pi(g^{-1})$ does not appear with a transpose in $({\color{green}\triangle})$.

---

We can generalize further still to include your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4714354/kernel-of-an-operator-constructed-from-an-irrep-of-a-finite-group):

$$ T(M)=\frac{d_3}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}\chi_3(g^{-1})\,\pi_1(g)M\pi_2(g^{-1}), \tag{$\color{blue}☾$}$$

where a third irrep $(V_3,\pi_3)$ has character $\chi_3=\mathrm{tr}\,\pi_3$ and dimension $d_3=\chi_3(e)$. Now, $T$ is the isotypical projector onto the $V_3$-component of $\hom(V_2,V_1)$ as a rep. For $\pi_3$ trivial this re-establishes the above conclusions.

---

One textbook application of $T(M)=\delta_{\pi_1\pi_2}\frac{\mathrm{tr}\,M}{d_1}I$ from $({\color{green}\triangle})$ is Schur Orthogonality for Matrix Coefficients. This was relevant to your [next question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4715542/identity-with-outer-automorphism-for-finite-group-irrep).

If we pick the standard basis matrix $M=e_{jk}$ and look at the $i\ell$ entry of $T(M)$, on the one hand we get $\delta_{\pi_1\pi_2}\frac{\mathrm{tr}\,e_{jk}}{d_1}I_{i\ell}=\delta_{\pi_1\pi_2}\delta_{jk}\delta_{i\ell}/d_1$ from ($\color{green}{\triangle2}$). On the other hand, from ($\color{green}{\triangle1}$) we get

$$ \frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}\sum_{j',k'}\pi_1(g)_{ij'}(\delta_{jj'}\delta_{kk'})\pi_2(g^{-1})_{k\ell}. $$

Assuming $\pi_2$ is unitary so $\pi_2(g^{-1})=\pi_2(g)^\dagger=\overline{\pi_2(g)}^T$, this simplifies to

$$ \frac{\delta_{\pi_1\pi_2}\delta_{i\ell}\delta_{jk}}{d_1} = \frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}\pi_1(g)_{ij}\overline{\pi_2(g)}_{\ell k}. \tag{$\color{Purple}{\square}$}$$

These are the orthogonality relations.

---

If we (wlog) unitarize our irreps, then $\pi_2(g^{-1})^T=\overline{\pi_2(g)}$. Then we may set

$$ S(M)=\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}\pi_1(g)M\overline{\pi_2(g)}. \tag{$\color{orange}{\circ1}$}$$

The $i\ell$ matrix entry of $S(M)$ is given by

$$ S(M)_{i\ell} \,=\, \frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}\sum_{j,k}\pi_1(g)_{ij}M_{jk}\,\overline{\pi_2(g)}_{k\ell} $$

$$ =\, \sum_{j,k}M_{jk}\big(\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G} \pi_1(g)_{ij}\overline{\pi_2(g)}_{k\ell}\big)
$$

$$ =\, \sum_{j,k}M_{jk}\frac{\delta_{\pi_1\pi_2}\delta_{ik}\delta_{j\ell}}{d_1} \,=\, \frac{\delta_{\pi_1\pi_2}}{d_1} M_{\ell i}. $$

Therefore we may conclude

$$ S(M)=\frac{\delta_{\pi_1\pi_2}}{d_1}M^T. \tag{$\color{orange}{\circ2}$}$$

Comment: @IanGershonTeixeira No, I mean $M^T$. The only trivial irrep is 1D, and in 1D we have $M^T=M$, but in higher dimension we must say $M^T$. I plan respond to that new question soon.

Comment: Oh oops you're right my previous comment was way over generalizing from the fact that $ M=M^T $ for a $ 1 \times 1 $ matrix

Comment: Ok another possible typo? I agree with your conclusion $ \tag{$\color{orange}{\circ2}$} $. But in the line directly above that equality $ \, \sum_{j,k}M_{jk}\big(\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G} \pi_1(g)_{ij}\overline{\pi_2(g)}_{k\ell}\big)
\,=\, \sum_{j,k}M_{jk}\frac{\delta_{ik}\delta_{j\ell}}{d_1}  $ the right hand side seems to be missing a $ \delta_{\pi_1 \pi_2} $. And for the next equality $   \sum_{j,k}M_{jk}\frac{\delta_{ik}\delta_{j\ell}}{d_1} 
\,=\, M_{\ell i}  $ the right hand side seems to be missing a $ 1/d_1 $.

Comment: Also what does the $ d $ in line $ \tag{$\color{Magenta}\diamondsuit$} $ denote ?

Comment: @IanGershonTeixeira Typos fixed.

Answer (score 2):

What you wrote isn't right, and my guess is that basically any example will break it. It can be fixed though by adding a transpose:

$$ \sum_{g \in G}  \pi_1(g)   \pi_2(g^{-1})^\top = 0$$

Let's go back to character orthogonality to see where this is coming from. I claim that sum $\sum_{g \in G} Tr( \pi_1(g) )  Tr ( \pi_2(g^{-1}) )$ should really be thought of as $\sum_{g \in G} Tr(\pi_1(g) \otimes \pi_2^*(g))$, where $\pi_2^*(g)$ is the dual representation.  In terms of matrices the dual representation looks like $\pi_2^*(g) = \pi_2(g^{-1})^\top$, and the tensor product is given by the Knonecker product of matrices.

Recall that if $\pi$ is any representation then $\frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G} \pi(g)$ is a $G$-equivariant projection onto the subspace of $G$ invariant vectors. (To see that check that it squares to itself so it's a projection, that it commutes with every $g \in G$, that it fixes all $G$ invariant vectors, and that any vector in the image is $G$ invariant.) In particular the trace of this operator gives the multiplicity of the trivial representation in $\pi$.

Now to see why I wrote it that funny way: We can recover the usual orthogonality for characters by applying the above to $\pi =  \pi_1 \otimes \pi_2^*$ and noting that $\pi_1 \otimes \pi_2^*$ has a copy of the trivial representation iff $\pi_2  = \pi_1$, in which case it has multiplicity 1.  This is because tensor products and duals are defined so that $Hom_G(\pi_1 \otimes \pi_2^*, \mathbb{C}) = Hom(\pi_1, \pi_2)$ and we know there is a map between two irreducibles iff they are isomorphic, in which case there is a one dimensional space of maps (that is Schur's lemma).

Let's just not take trace. $\frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G} \pi_1(g) \otimes \pi_2^*(g)$ is the projection onto the invariant subspace of $\pi_1 \otimes \pi_2^*$, and therefore is $0$ if $\pi_2  \ne \pi_1$.  This is true for any irreps $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$, regardless of their sizes.

To get the version of statement you want, with the product of matrices rather than the tensor product, just note that the multiplication map $Mat_{n \times n} \times Mat_{n \times n} \to Mat_{n \times n}$ is bilinear so it corresponds to a linear map $Mat_{n \times n} \otimes Mat_{n \times n} \to Mat_{n \times n}$ and the sum we care about is the image of $\frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G} \pi_1(g) \otimes \pi_2^*(g) = 0$ under a linear map.

Comment: Wow I love the detail in this answer, it's especially helpful that you pointed out the identity $ Hom(\pi_1 \otimes \pi_2^*, \mathbb{C})= Hom(\pi_1, \pi_2) $ which as you note vanishes for distinct irreps and equals one for isomorphic irreps. I'm also going to go back in and edit my question so that it makes more sense

Comment: How does your reformulation using the transpose circumvent the objection raised in the comment from Kenta S? Can I think of $ \pi_1, \pi_2 $ being unitary reps so $ \pi_2(g^{-1})^T=(\pi_2(g)^{-1})^T=\pi_2(g)^* $ is just a complex conjugate? If we are just changing inverse to complex conjugate then how does that circumvent the "it's not basis independent"/"it's not conjugation invariant" objection of Kenta S?

Comment: Does the version of this result with $ \pi(g^{-1})^T $ hold for all fields? And it's just that when we specialize to the complex case we can use unitarity to simplify this expression to  $ \pi(g^{-1})^T =\pi(g)^* $?

Comment: One applies $\sum\pi_1(g)\otimes\pi_2(g^{-1})^T$ to a tensor of column vectors (or use Kronecker products). To apply it to a matrix, one doesn't use the transpose on the right anymore, so your first equation is not actually connected directly to your tensor expression. Also, OP's original orthogonality equation was right and arguably more natural than the one with the transpose, as I discuss in my answer.