# Identity with outer automorphism for finite group irrep.

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory, automorphism-group

Let $ G $ be a finite group. Let $ \pi: G \to GL(V) $ be a degree $ d $ irreducible representation of $ G $. Let $ \sigma $ be an automorphism of $ G $ such that $ \sigma(\pi) $ is a distinct irreducible representation from $ \pi $. Is it the case that
$$
0= \sum_{g \in G} \pi(g) \pi(\sigma(g))
$$
Or perhaps
$$
0= \sum_{g \in G} \pi(g) \pi(\sigma(g))^*
$$
where $ * $ denotes complex conjugate and we are now assuming that $ \pi: G \to GL_d(\mathbb{C}) $ is a complex representation. If so, is there any nice direct proof of this fact?

Comment: @Digitallis yes I'll clarify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\pi, \pi'$ be two distinct complex irreps of a finite group. The Great Orthogonality Theorem states that
$$\sum_{g \in G} \pi(g)_{ij} \pi'(g)_{i'j'}^* = 0$$
where $i, j, i', j'$ are *any* matrix coordinates in the appropriate ranges, and $*$ denotes complex conjugation. (We need not even assume $\pi, \pi'$ are of the same dimension, only that they are distinct irreps.)

Now assume $\dim \pi = \dim \pi' = d$. We have
$$\sum_{g \in G} \pi(g) \pi'(g)^* = \sum_{g \in G} \left(\sum_{k = 1}^d \pi(g)_{ik} \pi'(g)_{kj}^*\right)_{ij} = \left(\sum_{k = 1}^d \sum_{g \in G} \pi(g)_{ik} \pi'(g)_{kj}^*\right)_{ij} =0$$
where $(a_{ij})_{ij}$ denotes the matrix with $(i, j)$-entry $a_{ij}$, and we apply the Great Orthogonality Theorem to deduce that every coordinate is $0$. So the second version of your statement is the correct one.

Comment: Is there any analogue of this result over other fields? (say finite fields) Or is the complex conjugate indispensable? For example could we reinterpret the $ \pi(g)^* $ as $ (\pi(g)^{-1})^T $ since they are equivalent for unitary matrices?  In other words is it true that $ \sum_{g \in G} \pi(g) (\pi'(g)^{-1})^T =0 $ over any field?

Comment: @IanGershonTeixeira Yes, that should be right; see also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4714534/is-there-some-sort-of-irrep-orthogonality-for-finite-groups?rq=1

Comment: I explain in my answer to the linked question that $\sum \pi_1(g)M\pi_2(g^{-1})=0$ (when $\pi_!\not\cong\pi_2$) is the "natural" orthogonality relation, a textbook application of this fact is Schur Orthogonality for matrix coefficients, and the latter orthogonality relations in turn imply $\sum \pi_1(g)M\overline{\pi_2(g)}=0$. This I think is the appropriate order in which these two kinds of orthogonality are deduced.